# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < (anonymous function) on console

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am creating an upload file application. I wrote it using AJAX and PHP.

It is working fine on the localhost but when I uploaded it to my web server. It returns the error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

It is pointing to the line

```
uploaded = JSON.parse(this.response);
```

This line is in my upload.js script file

**upload.js**

```
var app = app || {};
(function (obj) {
"use stricts;"
var ajax, getFormData, setProgress;
ajax = function(data){
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(), uploaded;
    xmlhttp.addEventListener('readystatechange', function(){
        if (this.readyState === 4) {
            if (this.status === 200) {
                uploaded = JSON.parse(this.response);
                if (typeof obj.options.finished === 'function') {
                    obj.options.finished(uploaded);
                }
            }else{
                if (typeof obj.options.error === 'function') {
                    obj.options.error();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    xmlhttp.upload.addEventListener('progress',function(){
        var percent;

        if (event.lengthComputable === true) {
            percent = Math.round((event.loaded / event.total) * 100);
            setProgress(percent);
        }
    });

    xmlhttp.open('post', obj.options.processor);
    xmlhttp.send(data);

};

getFormData = function(source){
    var data = new FormData(), i;

    for(i=0; i<source.length; i = i+1){
        data.append('file[]',source[i]);
    }
    data.append('ajax', true);
    return data;
};

setProgress = function (value){
    if (obj.options.progressBar !== undefined) {
        obj.options.progressBar.style.width = value ? value + '%': 0;
    }

    if (obj.options.progressText !== undefined) {
        obj.options.progressText.innerText = value ? value + '%' : 0; 
    }
};

obj.uploader = function(options){
    obj.options = options;

    if (obj.options.files !== undefined) {
        ajax(getFormData(obj.options.files.files));
    }
}
}(app));
```

Here are the other codes for reference

**upload.php**

```
 <?php
 header('Content-Type: application/JSON');
 $uploaded = [];
 $allowed = ['jpg'];
 $succeeded = [];
 $failed = [];
 if (!empty($_FILES['file'])) {

 foreach ($_FILES['file']['name'] as $key => $name) {

    if($_FILES['file']['error'][$key] === 0){
        $temp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $ext = explode('.', $name);
        $ext = strtolower(end($ext));

        $file = md5_file($temp) . time() .'.'.$ext;

        if (in_array($ext,$allowed) === true && move_uploaded_file($temp, "uploads/{$file}") === true) {
                $succeeded [] = array('name' => $name, 'file' => $file);

            # code...
        }else{
            $failed[] = array('name' => $name );
        }

    }else{

        echo "Error";
    }
}
}

if (!empty($_POST['ajax'])) {
echo json_encode(array(
'succeeded' => $succeeded, 
'failed' =>$failed
));
}
?>
```

and here's my html form

**index.php**

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload" class="upload">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Upload Files</legend>
        <input type="file" id="file" name="file[]" required multiple>
        <input type="button" id="submit" value="Upload">
    </fieldset>
    <div class="bar">
        <span class="barfill" id="pb"><span class="barfilltext" id="pt">40%</span></span>
    </div>
    <div id="uploads" class="uploads">

    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="upload.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
            var f = document.getElementById('file'),
                pb = document.getElementById('pb'),
                pt = document.getElementById('pt');

                    app.uploader({
                    files:f,
                    progressBar:pb,
                    progressText:pt,
                    processor: 'upload.php',

                    finished: function(data){
                        var uploads = document.getElementById('uploads'),
                            succeeded = document.createElement('div'),
                            failed = document.createElement('div'), anchor, span, x;

                            if (data.failed.length) {
                                failed.innerHTML = '<p>The following files failed to upload</p>'
                            }
                            uploads.innerText = '' ;
                                anchor = document.createElement('p');
                                anchor.innerText = "Upload Completed!";
                                anchor.target = '_blank';
                                succeeded.appendChild(anchor);
                            for(x=0;x<data.failed.length; x=x+1){
                                span = document.createElement('span');
                                span.innerText = data.failed[x].name;
                                failed.appendChild(span);   
                            }
                            uploads.appendChild(succeeded);
                            uploads.appendChild(failed);
                    },
                    error: function (){
                        console.log("Error");
                    }
                });
            });
    </script>
</form>
```

This code works on the localhost. It is uploading the files to my localhost server and shows the loading progressbar.

But when I deploy this to my web server it shows the progressbar loading slowly until it reaches 100%. But when I look into the uploads directory in my server nothing was uploaded.

Comment: Use your browser's developer tools. Look at the Net tab. Look to see what response you are actually getting.

Comment: As Quentin says, the error is stemming from the fact that the parser cannot cast the returned data to valid JSON. Without seeing what the exact response is we can't help, although it sounds like you're getting HTML back, given the `<` character.

Comment: hi. since i cannot post images yet i uploaded the screenshot of the console log https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwkoZTNT2pYwNmxuMDdMNVMyVzQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Your upload.php is returning an error, which cant be parsed by JSON.parse, open the Network tab in dev tools (chrome), do the action again to get the error then in the network tab click on upload.php then click Response and you will see what upload.php is returning

Comment: it's pointing on line 3 of upload.php.
I don't know what's wrong with it..

this line
    <?php
    .
    .
    $uploaded = [];
    .
    .
    .

    ?>

Answer (score 1):

you have a missing `}` at the end of the code in upload.php, before the php end (`?>`):

```
'failed' =>$failed
));
}
}
?>
```